# Hausdorff Dimension and Hausdorff measure

Tags: real-analysis, hausdorff-measure

These are homework questions:
Give examples of the following spaces

1. Uncountable metric space with Hausdorff dimension 0.
2. $\dim X=1$ with Hausdorff dimension 1 measure measure = 0.

I can't think there is any connection between countable and measure.
I have a vagure idea that the first example should be somehow modified Cantor set, each time we remove an interval with length = $c_n$, with $\sum c_n=1$. But is this set still uncountable?

Comment: Cantor-type sets are uncountable no matter what the length of removed intervals. (It's a general theorem about compact sets without isolated points.) Hausdorff dimension is related to covering the set by small sets. In case of Cantor-type constructions, you cover the set by the intervals you have at step N.

Comment: Thanks Leonid. I still confused on how to calculate the Hausdorff measure of the general cantor set, since it needs to take infimum over all coverings with diameter $\epsilon$ and then let it goes to zero. Why covered by the intervals is enough?

Comment: The infimum certainly cannot be negative. Thus, if you can find coverings with arbitrarily small sum $\sum (\dots )^d$, it follows that the infimum is zero.

Answer (score 1):

If $(X,\rho)$ is a metric space, then for any subset $S$, we have $$
H_\delta^d(S):=\inf\ \{ \sum_{i=1}^\infty ({\rm diam}\ U_i)^d |
S\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty U_i,\ {\rm diam}\ U_i  < \delta \} $$
 where the infimum is over all countable covers of $S$. Then we have $H^d(S):=\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0 } H^d_\delta (S)$,
which is called the $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.

(1) If $C$ is Cantor set, then two intervals of length $\frac{1}{3}$
cover $C$ So $$H^d_\delta (C) \leq 2(\frac{1}{3})^d,\
\delta=\frac{1}{3}
$$

Considering construction of $C$, we have $$H^d_\delta (C) \leq
2^n(\frac{1}{3})^{nd},\ \delta=\frac{1}{3^n} $$

That is dimension is $ H^d(C)=1,\ \infty,\ 0$ when $d=d_0:=\ln_32$,
$d<d_0$, $d
> d_0$ respectively So $1$-dimension Hausdorff measure is $0$